# Is there any way to set DataGrid limit count of Rows?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, row

At runtime, I got data from DB that will be use to bind in DataGrid **first**.

And, I don't want to show over 30 rows.

For example, if number of data is 78 , then I show only 30 recently rows.

And if number of data is 14, then I show all 14 rows.

I mean, I want to set limit rows count in DataGrid.

In addition, if the row added, I want to hide last row and show new row.

Also, if the row deleted, I want to add last another row.

I want to keep 30 rows or less than.

How can I do this?

Here is a part of my code, but it can help only one case when a row added while the program executing.

```
private void IncidentList_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        IEditableCollectionView itemsView = this.incidentList.Items;
        if (this.incidentList.Items.Count == max_RowCount + 1 && itemsView.IsAddingNew == true)
        { // max_RowCount = 30
            itemsView.CommitNew();
            this.incidentList.CanUserAddRows = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ICollectionView` and bind your `ObservableCollection` to it.

Now you can apply filter on this collection view and put your condition there.